# Passing the ID of a DOM element to rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

My model has Chords, which have a many-to-many relationship with Notes through Chordnotes. My chords/show looks like this:

```
      <% @chord.notes.each do |note| %>
        <li id="NoteID<%= note.id %>" >
          <span class="content"><%= note.name %> (<%= note.description %>) (ID: <%= note.id %>)</span>
          <span class="timestamp">
            Created <%= time_ago_in_words(note.created_at) %> ago.
          </span>
          <span class="content">
            <%= link_to "remove (not working)", '#' %>
          </span>
        </li>
      <% end %>
```

I want the link_to tag to remove, not the note, but the Chordnote that links the Note to the Chord. I was trying to do this by referencing the #id in the < li > tag, which is the ID of the Note, and passing the Note ID and the Chord ID from the /show page the user was on. My Chordnote controller looks like this:

```
def destroy
  @chord = Chord.find(chord-id) <-- how do I get this chord id??
  @note = Note.find(note-id) <-- how do I get this note id??
    Chordnote.find_by(note_id: @note.id, chord_id: @chord.id).destroy
  redirect_to chord_path(@chord)
end
```

This destroy action works when I hardcode chord-id and note-id with ID #'s, but I can't figure out how to pass the relevant Note and Chord IDs from the chords/show page.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is untested, mind you. But have you tried passing the relevant data through the link_to?

```
<% @chord.notes.each do |note| %>
  <li id="NoteID<%= note.id %>" >
    <span class="content"><%= note.name %> (<%= note.description %>) (ID: <%= note.id %>)</span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Created <%= time_ago_in_words(note.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
    <span class="content">
      <%= link_to "remove (not working)", {controller: "whatever_controller", action: "destroy", chord_id: @chord.id, note_id: note.id } %>
    </span>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

and then you would access these in the destroy method like so

```
def destroy
  @chord = Chord.find( params[:chord_id] )
  @note = Note.find( params[:note_id] ) <-- how do I get this note id??
   Chordnote.find_by(note_id: @note.id, chord_id: @chord.id).destroy
  redirect_to chord_path(@chord)
end
```